# Where can I see the amount of my sales without tax and sales?

Tags: reports

I've got different amounts on the dashboard and at reports. which one is the right one?

Answer (score 1):

Magento's storage and handling of sales information is something I have been studying and agonizing over for a few years now. Since 2001, I have automated the importing of our e-commerce sales into Quickbooks via the QODBC driver and php scripts that I have written, so I have experience using queries to harness sales data.

I have yet to make any two different "methods" of reporting show the same numbers. I haunt StackExchange a bit and have employed a few different techniques for getting sales information out of Magento. Sadly, the most inaccurate technique I tried was to use "Collections" via `Mage::GetModel()`.

It's ugly, but here's the most accurate query I could come up with:

```
SELECT sfi.grand_total as 'total',sfii.base_row_total as 'sales', sfii.sku as 'sku',
sfii.name as 'desc', sfii.qty as 'qty', sfo.increment_id as 'order', 
sfi.shipping_amount as 'shipping', sfi.updated_at as 'date', 
sfii.tax_amount as 'tax_amount', sfo.customer_id, 
sfop.additional_information as 'pmt_details', 
sfo.customer_firstname as 'first', sfo.customer_lastname as 'last' 
FROM sales_flat_invoice_item sfii 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_invoice sfi ON sfii.parent_id = sfi.entity_id 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order sfo ON sfi.order_id = sfo.entity_id 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_payment sfop ON sfop.parent_id = sfo.entity_id
WHERE sfo.status = 'complete'
```

From this query, you can then combine the information how you need. In `php` this makes a large array of order lines. Further information can be gotten by using customer `group_id` information from the table `customer_entity`

ALSO note: on any given week, my report and Magento's built in sales report sometimes match until "last day's statistics" refresh is run. The Magento report I refer to is

```
Admin: Reports -> Sales -> Invoiced
    Match Period to: Last Invoice Created Date
    Order Status: Specified, Complete.
```

Ultimately, I chose to use ECC desktop to import orders from Magento and update Quickbooks. Should the tax men come audit me, I want to be able to point the legal finger at them. Tax MEN, as in sales tax or the IRS. When I critiqued the numbers (over months), I lost more and more confidence in Magento as a whole: I didn't like the internal sales report and I couldn't prove my query was reality. If the tax man asked me "do you trust your numbers with jail time?", as a Software Engineer, I wouldn't be able to say yes.
Running sales reports from Quickbooks that ECC have imported are the closest anything has gotten to the numbers my query produces.

**Description and example of above query**

Alteration of the above query to pare down the information:

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT(sfi.grand_total, 2) as 'total'
, FORMAT(sfii.base_row_total,2) as 'sales'
, sfii.sku as 'sku'
, FORMAT(sfii.qty,0) as 'qty'
, SUBSTRING(sfo.increment_id, 5) as 'order'
, FORMAT(sfi.shipping_amount,2) as 'shipping'
, date_format(sfi.updated_at, '%b %e') as 'date'
, FORMAT(sfii.tax_amount,2) as 'tax'
FROM sales_flat_invoice_item sfii 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_invoice sfi ON sfii.parent_id = sfi.entity_id 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order sfo ON sfi.order_id = sfo.entity_id 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_payment sfop ON sfop.parent_id = sfo.entity_id
WHERE sfo.status = 'complete' 
ORDER BY sfo.increment_id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
;
```

Gives this output:

```
+--------+--------+-------------+------+-------+----------+--------+-------+
| total  | sales  | sku         | qty  | order | shipping | date   | tax   |
+--------+--------+-------------+------+-------+----------+--------+-------+
| 28.67  | 15.00  | SG_Hose_Kit | 1    | 36916 | 13.67    | Oct 13 | 0.00  |
| 50.06  | 24.95  | SH-1199SW   | 1    | 36915 | 8.83     | Oct 13 | 0.00  |
| 50.06  | 15.75  | G1835       | 1    | 36915 | 8.83     | Oct 13 | 0.00  |
| 50.06  | 16.80  | G1753       | 1    | 36915 | 8.83     | Oct 13 | 0.00  |
| 96.33  | 36.22  | 52604R-14   | 1    | 36914 | 8.73     | Oct 13 | 0.00  |
| 96.33  | 51.39  | TB800       | 2    | 36914 | 8.73     | Oct 13 | 0.00  |
| 106.28 | 89.84  | TB1100      | 2    | 36913 | 9.25     | Oct 13 | 7.19  |
| 208.15 | 130.01 | IPF2C/B     | 2    | 36912 | 7.25     | Oct 13 | 10.40 |
| 208.15 | 56.00  | MAR9A-J     | 4    | 36912 | 7.25     | Oct 13 | 4.48  |
| 44.55  | 36.22  | 52616R-14   | 1    | 36911 | 8.33     | Oct 13 | 0.00  |
+--------+--------+-------------+------+-------+----------+--------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.40 sec)
```

`total` is the total amount invoiced for that order. For for order 36914, there are 2 lines in the invoice. "Lines" is synonymous for individual sku's in the order. `sales` is the dollar amount of that sku * qty. The `shipping` and `tax` columns are the total for that order (meaning redundant on a per-line basis, just like the `total` column).